# Prove that if $y \neq 0$ and $n$ is odd, then $x^n+y^n=(x+y)^n$ only if $x=0$ or $x=-y$ (Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 11)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following is a problem from Spivak's Calculus, ch. 11, "Significance of the Derivative".

> 63. (b) Prove that if $y \neq 0$ and $n$ is odd, then $x^n+y^n=(x+y)^n$ only if $x=0$ or $x=-y$.

**My question is:**  **is the following proof correct?**

> Assume $y \neq 0$ and $n$ odd. Then $n-1$ is even.
>
> Let $f(x)=x^n+y^n-(x+y)^n$.
>
> Let $x_0$ be a number such that $f(x_0)=0$.
>
> **Case 1: $y<0$**
>
> Assume $x_0>0$.
>
> Apply Rolle's Theorem to $f$ on $[0,x_0]$.
>
> $$\exists c, c \in (0,x_0) \land f'(c)=nc^{n-1}-n(c+y)^{n-1}=0$$
>
> $$c^{n-1}=(c+y)^{n-1}$$
>
> $$\pm c=c+y\tag{2}$$
>
> Case 1.1: $c=c+y$
>
> $$y=0$$ $$\bot$$
>
> Case 1.2: $-c=c+y$
>
> $$y=-2c$$
>
> Therefore, if $y=-2c<0$ and $x_0>0$, then
> $f(x_0)=x_0^n+y^n-(x_0+y)^n=0$.
>
> Ie, $x_0=-y$.
>
> Now assume $x_0<0$.
>
> $$\exists c, c \in (x_0, 0) \land f'(c)=nc^{n-1}-n(c+y)^{n-1}=0$$
>
> $$c^{n-1}=(c+y)^{n-1}$$
>
> $$\pm c=c+y$$
>
> Case 1.1: $c=c+y$
>
> $$y=0$$ $$\bot$$
>
> Case 1.2: $-c=c+y$
>
> $$y=-2c>0$$
>
> $$\bot$$
>
> Case 2, where we assume $y>0$ is analogous. We reach pretty much
> exactly the same result.

**But what is the result after all? There seems to be something weird about the logical structure of this proof. It seems to somewhat have the correct result, but I can't tell exactly what it is.**

Note: I am aware of another simpler, more elegant proof. I am specifically interested in the possibility of constructing a proof by cases similar to the one above.

EDIT: The problem statement seems to be inaccurate. It should say $n$ odd and $n \geq 3$, because for $n=1$, $x^1+y^1= (x+y)^1$ for all $x$

Comment: I think there is a typo in the problem statement , should be x=0 or x= -y or x=y.

Comment: how are you deriving $\pm c = c+y$ immediately from $c^{n-1} = (c+y)^{n-1}$ ? Are you assuming a similar result for even exponents?

Comment: also, the next line you are saying:
$$x_0^n + y^n - (x+y)^n=0\implies x_0=-y$$
how is this implication justified?

Comment: @Salcio I checked the problem statement. It is correct. Indeed $x=y$ is not a valid solution to $f(x)=0$ because $f(y)=2y^n-2^ny^n=y^n(2-2^n)\neq 0$

Comment: @dezdichado since $n$ is odd, then $n-1$ is even. Therefore we get the $\pm$ when we take the $(n-1)$th root.

Comment: @dezdichado I've made the small correction. The correct statement is $x_0^n+y^n-(x_0+y)^n=0$. Note $f(x_0)=0$ by assumption, $x_0>0$, and this results in $y=-2c$. Though I think each logical step is correct, the conclusion seems awkward. It says that yes, if we assume that $y<0$ and $x_0>0$, and $f(x_0)=0$, then this is compatible with $y=-2c$, where $0<c<x_0$. Thus we can actually conclude that $x_0=2c$

Comment: @evianpring: what if $n=1$?

Comment: If $n=1$ then we have $f(x)=x+y-(x+y)=0$, so the statement is true for all $x$. I guess the problem statement needs to be changed to $n$ odd and $n>1$.

Comment: @evianpring 1) $\,x_0\,$ depends on $\,y\,$. 2) Rolle's theorem does not guarantee that $\,c\,$ is unique.

Comment: $y<0$ is given. We assume $f(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0>0$. Rolle tells us that there is some $0<c<x_0$ such that $f'(c)=0$. This leads to $y=-2c$, or $c=-\frac{y}{2}$. So this line of reasoning determines what $c$ must is. But since we now know what $y$ is in terms of $c$ and we know that $f(x_0)=0$, we are left with a degree $n$ equation in $x_0$ to solve. The equation is $x_0^n-(2c)^n-(x_0-2c)^n=0$. Clearly, $x_0=2c=-y$ is a solution. The missing aspect of this reasoning seems to be showing that this is the only solution for this case.